# Implementing Proactive Events in Alexa

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Hi I am having a difficult time enabling proactive events in my Alexa Skill. Here is what I have already done and is working perfectly :

My skill is active in development phase and I am able to discover my smart devices through it, switch on/off using the skill. I am using Google OAuth2 in account linking for my Alexa Skill.

To enable the proactive events, I went to Alexa Developer Console > Build > Permissions > Enabled 'Send Alexa Events'

Then I used Alexa CLI and added this to my skill.json manifest :

```
 "permissions": [
      {
        "name": "alexa::async_event:write"
      },
      {
        "name": "alexa::devices:all:notifications:write"
      }
```

I have also implemented the event handler in my lambda function and I can see a Alexa.Authorization / Alexa.AcceptGrant request coming into my lambda function, here is how I am handling the directive in my Lambda function :

```
//AUTHORIZATION ACCEPT GRANT
async function handleAcceptGrant(request, context) {
        console.log("REQUEST : ", request);
      try {
   
      // Build the response
      const response = {
        event: {
          header: {
            namespace: AUTHORIZATION,
            name: AcceptGrant,
            messageId: createMessageId(),
            payloadVersion: '3'
          },
          payload: {}
        }, 
 
      }
    console.log(response);
    return response;
        // If the directive is not Alexa.Authorization, return an error response
    return createErrorResponse('INVALID_DIRECTIVE', 'This skill only supports Alexa.Authorization directives.');
   }catch (error) {
    console.error('Error handling directive:', error);
    return createErrorResponse('INTERNAL_ERROR', 'An internal error occurred while handling the directive.');
  }
```

Response, my lambda function is sending :

```
 {
  event: {
    header: {
      namespace: 'Alexa.Authorization',
      name: 'AcceptGrant',
      messageId: 'e5c70465-c805-4b49-a3ca-33bee98b9fb3',
      payloadVersion: '3'
    },
    payload: {}
  }
}
```

However, since I made these changes, I am unable to link my account in the Alexa App with my Skill. I also tried to make a post call in Postman to https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token with the following fields : grant_type, client_id, client_secret and scope. Where scope="alexa::proactive_events". The response I get from the Amazon server is 'Invalid Scope'.

I am not sure how to proceed and feel lost. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming conventions and terminology here can get a little muddled so I totally understand where you're coming from. Let's start by taking a step back and describing the features associated with the two permissions you've listed.

### Alexa Event Gateway

- Permission Name In `skill.json` Manifest: `alexa::async_event:write`
- Skill Type Supported: Smart Home Skills Only

When creating a [smart home skill](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/understand-the-smart-home-skill-api.html), toggling the "Send Alexa Events" permission switch adds the `alexa::async_event:write` permission to your skill's manifest. This permission allows you to *proactively* send a [ChangeReport](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-changereport.html#change-reporting), an [AddOrUpdateReport](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-discovery.html#add-or-update-report) or [DeleteReport](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-discovery.html#deletereport-event) event to the [Alexa Event Gateway](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/send-events-to-the-alexa-event-gateway.html).

In this way, you can tell Alexa when a customer has added a new device to their device cloud, removed a device, or interacted with a device, even when those interactions happened without the customer interacting directly with an Alexa device.

For example, if I have a customer with a [contact sensor](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-contactsensor.html) attached to a door, and they physically open the door, I can send a `ChangeReport` to the Alexa Event Gateway reporting that the `detectionState` property changed to `DETECTED` (open) as result of a `PHYSICAL_INTERACTION`. Proactively reporting these changes in device properties has multiple benefits, a big one that your customers can create routines in their Alexa apps using these changes in device state as triggers.

### Proactive Events

- Permission Name In `skill.json` Manifest: `alexa::devices:all:notifications:write`
- Skill Type Supported: Custom Skills Only

When creating a [custom skill](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/understanding-custom-skills.html), you may optionally choose to enable "Proactive Events". The [Proactive Events API](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/proactive-events-api.html) allows you to make an API call to send notifications to your skill customers. Those notifications must conform to one of a number of pre-defined [Proactive Events Schemas](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/schemas-for-proactive-events.html).

For example, if I had a trash collection custom skill and I wanted to tell my customers that the coming Monday is trash collection day, I could send an `AMAZON.TrashCollectionAlert.Activated` event to notify them.

### Recommendations

The recommendations below are operating from the assumption that you are indeed working with a smart home skill and that your goal is to send smart home events to the "Alexa Event Gateway":

1. Remove the `alexa::devices:all:notifications:write` permission from your smart home skill's manifest. This permission is not supported by smart home skills.
2. When making the call to the `/auth/o2/token` endpoint to get your `access_token` and `refresh_token` *remove* the `alexa::proactive_events` scope added previously.

As a point of reference, here's a screen-shot of my own, working, Postman request in which I receive an `access_token` and `refresh_token`:
[image]